# Hermes JMS with SOAPUI - Message browse

Tags: soapui, ibm-mq, ready-api, hermes-jms

I am trying to work with the MQ messages in SOAPUI using hermes JMS.
I am able to send receive messages to the queues through a SOAP test request.
Plugin used in hermes is IBM Websphere MQ.

Now to the problem :)
 When I want to get the messages from queue, I just want to browse the message and not receive it, causing it to get removed from the Queue.
I have done this using groovy/JAVA by setting the MQ Open Options. But no where in hermes can I specify that I want to open a session just for browsing.

Any idea on this?

Comment: You need to write code using groovy / java to browse the message.

Comment: Yea, I agree. But cant I do it in hermesJMS? By setting some property under connection factory?

Comment: I believe you should be able to do so. Thought you might needed it programmability/

Comment: Oh no, not through a program... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not an answer to your question. but depending on your use case, you may be interested in [JMSToolBox on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you use case for using SoapUI, you may be interested by [JMSToolBox on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox)